# Centos 7 Apache and PHP5 Error: Package: php-5.6.40-21.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)

Tags: php, apache, nginx, centos

I try to install PHP 5.6 with

```
yum install php
```

I have CentOs 7 but get the follow error:

```
Error: Package: php-5.6.40-21.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
       Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
       Installed: httpd-2.4.6-93.el7.centos.x86_64 (@base)
           httpd-mmn = 20120211
           httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
```

Into the options, I follow these steps and not resolve the problem.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-cli (and other needed modules)
```

And you can also enable the repository for future update (as the "remi-php56" is safe and only provides php 5.6 and its extension)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32881532/2671354

Comment: Looks like a dependency issue. The php and php-cli packages are probably not dependent on the httpd package, so it is a bit weird dependency conflict. Do you have other versions of PHP installed? If so, you may want to try removing them. If that does not work as well, take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-5-6-on-centos-7/). I followed it step by step several times and never had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The capability `httpd-mmn = 20051115` is provded by the `httpd` package in the base repository ([reference](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64.rpm.html)).

Either you have disabled base CentOS 6 repository in `yum` configuration or its `.repo` definition file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` is missing.

In the latter case, reinstall the CentOS release package:

```
yum reinstall centos-release
```

Comment: I follow the instructions and seems like is installed correctly the PHP, but still only show me the code of PHP in the URL, not execute PHP

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install **EL-6** packages on **EL-7**, this cannot work.

Fix your repository configuration.

Also see the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

Comment: I follow the instructions and seems like is installed correct the php, but still only show me the code of php in the url, not execute php